# compile error with tiny http server c code gcc debian

Tags: c, socket

My distro is MX Linux (Debian)
GCC was already installed with distro.

I am trying to compile some open source code from Nir Lictman.
His [Minimalist C web server](https://gist.github.com/nir9/3d22d954a599a71c1ccf64ea63c4e38f) code compiles in his [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HrYIl6GpYg).

When I use gcc to compile, I get errors:

```
servera.c: In function ‘main’:
servera.c:21:13: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘bind’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   21 |     bind(s, &addr, sizeof(addr));
      |             ^~~~~
      |             |
      |             struct sockaddr_in *
In file included from servera.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:112:49: note: expected ‘const struct sockaddr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
  112 | extern int bind (int __fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t __len)
```

When I try to see the man page for netinet i get error:

```
$ man netinet
No manual entry for netinet
```

I did find a `netinet` directory that contains `in.h` at `/usr/include/netinet`. And that `in.h` has a definition of `sockaddr_in` as follows:

```
/* Structure describing an Internet socket address.  */
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);
    in_port_t sin_port;         /* Port number.  */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;        /* Internet address.  */

    /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'.  */
    unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr)
               - __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE
               - sizeof (in_port_t)
               - sizeof (struct in_addr)];
  };
```

However I wonder if the compiler is finding this definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example in [`man 2 bind`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html): standard practice here is to cast the pointer to the expected type. In your example:

```c
    bind(s, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen. It compiles now !  Did I get the port code correct? I run the executable.  I put simple index.htm in dir with this executable file. When I run the code and then browse with Firefox to either 127.0.0.1:8080/index.htm or 192.168.0.101:8080/index.htm I get Error, "Unable to Connect".

Comment: It works for me on 8080, as long as nothing else is already bound to that port; the program doesn’t handle errors, so if it fails to bind it will silently bind to a random port.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Thanks for hanging in there with me. I added many error traps: socket, bind, listen, accept, recv. All browsers say"connection refused". However, WGET actually works and reports "no headers. HTTP 0.9 assumed". And it DOES INDEED download the file. So I guess I have to somehow dress up the the response with headers to get minimal functionality with a browser - which is useful for me. Thank you again, my friend :-)

Comment: Oh right, yes, it won’t work with a modern browser (but I’d expect “connection reset” rather than “refused”).